# DataContractSerializer - Name cannot begin with the '.' character, hexadecimal value 0x2E

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

This question has been asked a lot of times on SO, but neither solution helped me.

My datastruct is serialized into an XML file using dataContractSerializer. The (de)serialization code is the following:

```
    public static void serialize<T>(T xObject, string xFilePath, string xIndent = "")
    {
        XmlWriterSettings xSettings = ( xIndent == "" ? new XmlWriterSettings  {Indent = false } : new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = xIndent } );

        using (XmlWriter xStream = XmlWriter.Create(xFilePath, xSettings))
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T)).WriteObject(xStream, xObject);
    }

    public static T deserialize<T>(string xFilePath)
    {
        using (FileStream xStream = new FileStream(xFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            DataContractSerializer xSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xSerializer.ReadObject(xStream);
        }
    }
```

A snippet of the written XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PxePriceListEod xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="libTypes.salesApp">
   <DateOfValidity xmlns:d2p1="libTypes">
       <d2p1:_x002E_>2016-09-09T00:00:00</d2p1:_x002E_>
   </DateOfValidity>
   <PriceRecords>
       <AbstractPxePriceRecordEod i:type="PxePriceRecordEodBal">
           <Product xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
               <d4p1:Ccy>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>EUR</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Ccy>
               <d4p1:Commodity>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>Electricity</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Commodity>
               <d4p1:Duration>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>Month</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Duration>
               <d4p1:Exchange>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>Pxe</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Exchange>
               <d4p1:Period>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>9</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Period>
               <d4p1:Type>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>Base</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Type>
               <d4p1:Year>
                   <d4p1:_x002E_>2016</d4p1:_x002E_>
               </d4p1:Year>
           </Product>
           <IsDeduced xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
               <d4p1:_x002E_>false</d4p1:_x002E_>
           </IsDeduced>
           <IsInterpolated xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
                  <d4p1:_x002E_>false</d4p1:_x002E_>
           </IsInterpolated>
           <IsSynthetic xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
               <d4p1:_x002E_>false</d4p1:_x002E_>
           </IsSynthetic>
           <Price xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
               <d4p1:_x002E_>30.45</d4p1:_x002E_>
           </Price>
           <DateOfValidity xmlns:d4p1="libTypes">
               <d4p1:_x002E_>2016-09-09T00:00:00</d4p1:_x002E_>
           </DateOfValidity>
       </AbstractPxePriceRecordEod>
       ... more AbstractPxePriceRecordEod elements ...
     </PriceRecords>
  </PxePriceListEod>
```

Features of the problem:

1. The error points to Line=0, Position=1 (which does not make sense)
2. There is no element with name containing "."
3. All classes that make it into the file are properly decorated with `DataContract`
4. The XML file is checked to really be in UTF-8 encoding (when read by Notepad++) and none of the other versions of (de)serializing code listed on SO (that implicitly specify UTF-8 encoding) helped
5. I know the file is ugly (autogenerated element names like "d4p1:*x002E*" - Im the only dev in this company and unfortunately I dont have time to nicely decorate 100+ classes)
6. Everything was working fine for 2.5 years, the problems started today.

Any hint is much appreciated, 
Daniel

**UPDATE**

I have added a minimal amount of code that reproduces the problem [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4073zhtgv6ea40c/so_39484145.rar?dl=0). The `application` tries to read the given class from an xml file, the classes that have the problematic dataContractNames are located in `library\+support\+qprimitive`.

Comment: You XML is not valid. *XML Parsing error at line 2: 
xmlns: URI libTypes.salesApp is not absolute* after validating your given example

Comment: `_x002E_` is how [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname(v=vs.110).aspx) encodes the string `"."`.  So your `<d2p1:_x002E_>` and `<d4p1:_x002E_>` elements all have local names that, when decoded, map to `"."`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/phUYO3.  Can you share the type corresponding to `DateOfValidity` so we can see how the XML was generated?  Is it implementing `IXmlSerializable` or `ISerializable`?

Comment: Better yet, can you share an [mcve] that serializes types that produce those `<d2p1:_x002E_>` elements?

Comment: @dbc: Thanks, this is it. One of my classes uses `[DataMember(Name = ".")]` - I was new to XML when I was writing this and I figured "let's make the XML smaller". The funny thing is that the runtime did not complain about this for years. Now ... having a lot of files that have been written using this format, what is the smallest change that I can make to the code that will make it possible for me to read these files? The class that uses this DataMemberName has only one member and is sealed. I tried using [DataMember(Order = 0)] instead of DataMemberName, but did not help. Many thanks!

Comment: @DanielBencik - I tried making a sample class with a `[DataMember(Name = ".")]`, and was able to deserialize it successfully.  In order to help more, can you share the classes that fail to deserialize the XML above?  Or can you identify what changed in the past few days through source control?  Without a [mcve] I'll be spending my time guessing what your class definitions are and experimenting to see if I can reproduce the problem, which is unlikely to succeed quickly.

Comment: @dbc: A have made an edit, the linked solution shows the problem. The "funny" thing is that this solution bugs on all files, even the ones on which the whole solution worked fine.

Comment: @dbc: anyway, I will correct it manually. Can you please make an answer out of your comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_x002E_` is how [`XmlConvert.EncodeLocalName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodelocalname(v=vs.110).aspx) encodes the string `"."`.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/phUYO3 for a demonstration.  So you either:

- Have a data member with `"."` as its name.
- Have implemented `IXmlSerializable` and are writing elements with this name.

That being said, making a data contract type with `[DataMember(Name = ".")]` on one of the data members does not cause problems for me.  I.e. I can serialize and deserialize the following successfully:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "libTypes.salesApp")]
public class PxePriceListEod
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateOfValidity DateOfValidity { get; set; }
}

// DateOfValidity 
[DataContract(Namespace = "libTypes")]
public class DateOfValidity
{
    [DataMember(Name = ".")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot. The problem with inheritance is my fault during the sample project creation - there was a list of approx. eight interfaces following the base class and during the deletion of the interfaces from the derived class declaration, I deleted the base class as well. I updated the linked solution. Secondly, however, when I run both the old and this updated solution, I still get the exception with ".". And I understand why you're not getting it ... I stopped receieving that exception yesterday at night - for no apparent reason.

Comment: @DanielBencik - so is your issue no longer reproducible?

Comment: It seems so. But, taking into account that when the runtime complains, it complains about "." I will more than gladly take your post as an answer.